# Encrypting passwords with SHA1 and + salt bcrypt?

Tags: security, cryptography, passwords, sha1, bcrypt

If I encrypt a password with SHA1 and then add salt to it and then encrypt it with bcrypt. Is it much safer than if I add salt salt to a not encrypted password and then encrypt it with bcrypt?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Computing a SHA-1 hash of the password before passing it on to bcrypt won't provide any additional security.

At best, it will retain the security of bcrypt. Applying SHA-1 to the initial password does neither add any additional entropy nor does it expand the range of the outcome in any way, and thus the security of the result will be at best only as good as that of bcrypt itself.

But [Antoine Joux](http://math.boisestate.edu/~liljanab/MATH509Spring2012/JouxAttackSHA-1.pdf)'s research has shown that it probably is even worse than that. With multicollisions, it might even happen that you weaken the security so that the resulting scheme is even *less* secure than using bcrypt alone.

In general, cryptographic primitives should best be used as specified. This gives you at least a little guarantee that the result will be secure - adding to a scheme manually "to improve" things will almost always end in something that is less secure than the original.